# (Angular2) FormArray hide previous form as new form added

Tags: angular, material-design, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a form array inside a formbuilder and i am dynamically changing forms, i.e. on click load data from application 1 etc.

The issue i am having is that all the data loads in but the data in the `formarray` stays and just concats the old items with new.

How do I make the `formarray` to only have the new array and hide the previous array. i am creating an array form using angular2.

[working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZLlOjsWfG0N6gcqvys1X?p=preview) of my project

Comment: Have you tried `form.reset()` to reset the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do what you want, but as per discussed elsewhere, here is no possibility to revisit the other form elements, that requires a little more tinkering :)

Just set a condition that checks whether the object is the last item in the `formArray`, and if it is, it displays only that object.

So where you are iterating the `objects` array add the following condition:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of myForm.controls.objects.controls; let i=index">
 <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngIf="i === myForm.controls.objects.controls.length -1">
```

Add these conditions inside the `formArray`s in the survey tab.

Forked

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/egfnq3rKEaY2bMqPk54B?p=preview)

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad to help! Have a great day and happy coding!

Comment: have a great day too.